# Can you specify a ViewChild as the ControlValueAccessor in a custom form control?

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

In reading [this blog](https://blog.angularindepth.com/never-again-be-confused-when-implementing-controlvalueaccessor-in-angular-forms-93b9eee9ee83), I came across the following quote:

> It’s usually the class of the component or directive that registers the provider

Meaning that it's specified as a `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR` provider in the `@Component` decorator.  I am curious about any *unusual* ways.  I've seen examples settting it directly on the `NgControl` via:

```
constructor(@Self() @Optional() private ngControl: NgControl) {
    if (this.ngControl) {
        this.ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
    }
}
```

However, I'm wondering if there is yet another alternative, one that will serve my use case...

I am 'extending' `MatSelect` with the addition of a filtering mechanism by creating a new component that leverages a `MatSelect` in its implementation/template.  Currently my component has to serve as the `ControlValueAccessor`.  Is there means that I can provide the underlying `MatSelect` instead?  I can access it via `@ViewChild`, however the accessor requirement is executed in `ngOnChanges()`, which is before the select becomes available in `ngAfterViewInit()`.